# How can malware remain on the Google Play store?

Tags: malware, android

How could an app that is malware be on the Google Play store?  I found a Bible app "Bible Home" (which exhibits malware like behavior) available for Android on the Play Store.  However, after installing it, I didn't see the app. My phone soon asked me if I wanted to use Launcher3 or this new app to be my app launcher - a BIG red flag since the app wasn't expected to be an app launcher. Reading further into it's detailed description reveals it is.  I chose Launcher3 to continue to be my app launcher and promptly deleted the new app.

It shocked me that it is a highly rated app (roughly 4.5 stars).  I don't know if most of those reviews are somehow fake, but there are a fair number of reviews (including mine) pointing to the malware-like behavior, and rating it 1 or 2 stars.

If you do let it become your app manager, I believe that would be giving it excessive, perhaps even root-like capability. There are other 1-star reviews that said that it takes over their phone (as the request to be the application manager led me to believe), and serves advertisements "outside" the app, drains the battery (perhaps bitcoin mining?), and degrades the performance of the phone.

As I have understood it, I thought the Google Play store was screened for malware. *I am wondering how such a highly rated app with over a million downloads could be seemingly malicious like that* My Verizon Secure app also didn't detect it as malware.

So, a few thoughts:

- This could been a legitimate app that the developer changed to add malware.
- This could have been a legitimate app somehow infected with malware (without developer involvement)
- It is disconcerting that someone would hide malware in such an innocent-looking (on the surface) application, but I suppose that is the point.
- It does say in the description of the app that it is an app manager, so perhaps many are okay with that, including the Google Play Store.

Comment: Let's look at this logically. You already know ***how*** malware could get highly rated (fake/purchased reviews), so let's remove that entire factor from your question. Now you are left with, "How does malware get on the Play Store?" and more specifically, "why did ***this app*** not get detected as malware by he Play Store and my mobile anti-virus?" Simple: because it isn't ***malware***. It's a PUP (potentially unwanted program). Basically, it's misnamed. ...

Comment: @schroeder - That would probably actually make a decent answer, along with my thoughts at the bottom of the question.  I am not really sure I agree it isn't malware, it is sort of a grey area.  It takes over as app manager, but that is also the stated functionality.  It tries to hide itself and prevent uninstalling.  It pushes unwanted ads to the phone, slows it down, drains the battery (and who knows what else behind the scenes).  Maybe it is that grey-ness that allows it to remain.

Comment: All kinds of legitimate apps serve ads. So, that's not suspicious. It says that it is an app manager, so that's not suspicious. And all kinds of apps can degrade performance, so, depending on what it is actually doing to consume resources, that's not suspicious either. ***From a code standpoint***. As I say, it's deceptively named. That's ultimately the only issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing a "deceptive" program with "malware". If the app is doing typical app things, like an app manager, then it's not malware.

You have a misnamed app doing things you would not expect a "bible" program to be doing. that's not malware. It's just deception.

So, from a code perspective, it's not doing anything wrong, so malware scanners would not pick up on it. It's just advertised to trick users into thinking it's doing something else.